# How this motor can be mounted?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I am a beginner to motors. For one of the projects, I am going to use this stepper motor: https://www.faulhaber.com/en/products/series/am1020/

I am trying to mount this motor to a plate, however, I could not find any holes to attach a motor bracket and mount it.(like the other motors I have seen) My question is: what would be possible solutions to mount this motor?

Comment: Make a clamp type bracket working on the diameter.

Comment: Cheers, meant no disrespect, just wanted to point out of easy it is to access information. @JRE

Comment: That is very debatable, what is a correct mounting and what is not. @JRE

Answer (score 7):

Turn to the 'drawings' tab on the data sheet you linked to. You'll see that the boss around the output shaft is threaded M5.5x0.5.

Drill a 5mm diameter hole in your plate, tap it M5.5, and screw the motor in.

You've done the right thing by choosing a motor with a data sheet (many don't). But you have to read it for it to work.

Comment: "Read it" or understand.  Just looking at the diagram, I didn't recognize the markings for what they were.  Without your hint, I would have missed the intention for those markings to represent a threaded mounting.